# Remove adjacent lines that match pattern

Tags: text-processing

Input: file with sorted lines

Output: file with 'unique' lines that match adjacent lines if we are to remove all digits

Example

Input

```
abbylove2007
abbylove2008
abbylove2012
AbbyLove2014
abby1994lover
abby2007lover
abbylovesaal2018
abbylovesbsb2003
```

Output

```
abbylove2007
abby1994lover
```

Here abbylove2007 and abby1994lover are left since there are more than one adjacent line that matches abbylove\d+ and abby\d+lover

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk '{ curr=$0; gsub("[0-9]","",curr) } curr != prev { prev=curr; prevfull=$0; flag=0; next } !flag { print prevfull; flag=1 }' test
abbylove2007
abby1994lover
```

First, remove digits from the current line. If the result of this is different from the previous line with digits removed, then update the previous line with this line, remember the full previous line, and set the `flag` variable to zero, then continue with the next line.

The `flag` variable is used when outputting line that are the same as the previous line to make sure that we only output the *first* of these lines.

For lines that are the same as the previous line (digits removed), if the flag isn't set, print the full previous line, then set the flag.

Comment: This worked. Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

That would be a modified sed equivalent of `uniq -d`:

```
sed '$!N; s/^\([^0-9]*\)\(.*\)\n\1[0-9].*$/\1\2/; t; D'
```